# django admin interface change_form.html add data to querydict / post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin, django-templates

is there a possibility to add data to the querydict / post variable via jQuery / javascript from within an admin template? 
i want to have some additional data submitted when clicking on admins built-in save-button.

greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This would mean that you have a security issue that can be seriously exploited via XSS attack.

To do this properly you'll want to subclass your custom forms and build additional views.